# How to get inserted value for trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in mysql that will insert in to another table when an insert on a table occurs.

```
CREATE TRIGGER addCardForNewUser AFTER INSERT ON swiped.Users
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO swiped.Card (userid) VALUES (get value from original insert here);
  END
```

In the values part of the insert statement how would i get a value from the original insert to use here?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use those values with `new.columnname`. If the name of the column is `userid` too, then you can use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addCardForNewUser AFTER INSERT ON swiped.Users
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO swiped.Card (userid) VALUES (new.userid);
  END
```

From the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access
>   columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL
>   extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive.
>
> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used