# How can I increase the value of an attribute of one table on the basis of the insertion of value to an attribute of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, database-trigger

I have two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
department_id INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
department_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
total_employees INT(4),
PRIMARY KEY (department_id),
UNIQUE (department_name));

CREATE TABLE `employees` (
employee_id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
employee_email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
employee_first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
employee_last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
department_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (employee_id),
UNIQUE (employee_email),
FOREIGN KEY (department_name)
    REFERENCES departments (department_name)
    ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Now, suppose I've a department which is HRM. 2 employees have HRM department. So, I want the value of total_employees of departments table 2 through a trigger. Would be great if I could get some suggestions of yours.

Comment: you don't really need to store the total number of employees in a field. You can just calculate it using a COUNT inside a query at the time when you want to know it. It's kind of a redundant piece of information. If you do really want to store it for some reason, then yes, you can write a trigger. But...what have you tried to do so far? What problem are you having? This isn't a free write-my-code or do-my-research service. You can find examples of this kind of trigger easily. There's no need for us to provide another tutorial here.

Comment: See, I ain't expecting you to solve my problem, I'm asking politely for some suggestions.

Comment: Ok thankyou. But that wasn't clear from the way you wrote the question before. We can't read your mind. Anyway, please add that code and error information into the question itself using the "edit" button...code in comments is hard to read, and people may not notice it. Comments are just for asking for clarifications / making brief suggestions, not for adding content which is fundamental to the question itself. Thanks.

Comment: If you not into suggesting, please ignore, I think there are people who would love to suggest.

Comment: SO is not a place for broad generic suggestions or code samples, especially on topics like this for which generic tutorials/solutions are already widely available. We are here to help with fixing _specific problems_. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance. Anyway I am happy to try and help with your code once we can see it easily.

Comment: Added the code that I tried with error, would appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184396/discussion-between-bappi-sb-and-adyson).

Comment: in an insert trigger there is no "old"...because you're inserting a row, not updating one. There is no previous version of the row, because it never existed before. You can just use the department_id in the newly created row using `new` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453535/how-to-get-inserted-value-for-trigger

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, it worked.

Comment: That's great to hear. I added as a full answer below, if you care to mark as accepted - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an insert trigger there is no "old"...because you're inserting a row, not updating one. There is no previous version of the row, because it never existed before. You can just use the department_id in the newly created row using `new` instead. And you don't need the `if` because there's nothing to compare to:

```
delimiter $$ 
create trigger employee_insertion_in_individual_department
  after insert on employees for each row begin

    update departments set total_employees=total_employees+1 
    where department_id=new.department_id; 

end$$ delimiter ;
```

See also [How to get inserted value for trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453535/how-to-get-inserted-value-for-trigger)

P.S. It might be safer to update this by using a count of the actual rows, rather than a simple increment. I'm worried it might go askew if lots of rows are changed at almost the same time. It may be worth testing whether this causes issues or not.

P.P.S. I assume you also plan to add UPDATE and DELETE triggers for the same purpose, if you haven't already.

Comment: One issue that I'm facing, would be great if you could give some ideas.

Comment: @Bappi_SB what issue are you referring to? If you have a new problem, please ask a new question about it. paste the question link in these comments if you'd like me to look at it. Thanks.

Comment: I've added it over here. Would be great if you could give your view on this.

Comment: Over this question. Edited it.

Comment: You can't really add new problems to an existing question once it's been answered. Otherwise in theory we could go on and on forever with new issues and it would not be the same question any more, plus it actually becomes multiple questions (instead of one) and is at risk of being closed as too broad. And it never attracts any more votes etc for both asker and answerer. Like I said, if you have a new problem, ask a new question (you can of course copy/paste a lot of the content from this one, if it's still relevant). And in the meantime, you should put this one back to the way it was. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, will be adding new question.

Comment: BTW I see in your history that someone answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850729/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-value-from-one-table-to-another-on-the-basis-of-value) a while ago giving you exactly the same kind of information as this one - i.e. that you need to use `new` to get data from the newly added record. Did you forget about that somehow?

Comment: I think i was trying to get a particular solution here, since was not working on database for few months, i might have forgotten, appreciate your answer. but this was not the solution I'm trying to get for the particular problem that I'm facing.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want an *update* trigger, not an *insert* trigger.  The *insert* trigger would be:

```
delimiter $$ 

create trigger employee_insertion_in_individual_department
after insert on employees for each row
begin
    update departments set 
        total_employees = total_employees + 1 
        where department_id = new.department_id;
    end if;
end$$

delimiter ;
```

The *update* trigger would be more like:

```
delimiter $$ 
create trigger employee_insertion_in_individual_department
after insert on employees for each row
begin
    if not (old.employee_department <=> old.employee_department) then
        update departments set 
            total_employees = total_employees + (case when department_id = old_department_id then -1 else 1 end)
            where department_id in (old.department_id, new.department_id);
    end if;
end$$

delimiter ;
```